# Remove items from list or add build a new list?

Tags: java, collections

Often I come to a point where I have to iterate an `ArrayList` and want to create a subset from it based on any condition.

From performance point of view: is it better to use iterator and `iterator.remove()` for the elements I want to remove, or should I add these elements to a new list?

```
for (Iterator<Object> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Object item = it.next();
    if (!conditionMatches(item)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

or

```
List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object item : list) {
   it (contitionMatches(item)) {
      newList.add(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: It depends on many things e.g. memory, speed, if this list will be reused or not, and on. It's not *that* simple to answer.

Comment: from a big-o perspective, in an ArrayList removing is O(n), adding is O(1) amortized. (other types of list have different complexity)

Comment: profile, profile, profile.  theory is fine but real numbers will speak for themselves.

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1** will not work for read-only lists such as those returned by `Arrays.asList`.

Also, `remove` from `ArrayList` is a significant cost when the list is long as much of the backing array must be copied.

**Option 2** will work for all lists.

It is also the pattern we are encouraged to use with streams:

```
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("A","B","C");
    List<String> filtered = l.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.equals("A"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

IMHO - Use this one. The savings in option 1 are illusory.

Comment: Option 1 will work because he use an iterator and not an arraylist

Answer (score 3):

**Time complexity: Option 2 is best**

**Space complexity: Option 1 is best**

ArrayList remove is O(n) while add is O(1), however, you will have to allocate new memory for the new list.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove just one element, you can do it either way. If you want to remove all the elements past a certain point, you can do it either way (iterating backwards for removal). In general, however, the copying approach is likely to take much less time. If you prefer to modify the list in place, you might consider [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-). Although the documentation does not indicate how it works, it most likely keeps track of a "to" and "from" index, shifting all the elements down in a single pass. Whether the copying or modifying approach fits best will certainly depend on how you are using the list, and (if my guess about `removeIf` is correct) may also depend on what fraction of the elements are removed.

Comment: It's worth to note that `removeIf` is available since Java 8.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I wouldn't know; I barely know Java. Before that, you could implement it yourself without much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove values from list you need to make it from end to start, like this:

```
for (int i=list.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
   if (contitionMatches(list.get(i))) {
       list.remove(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Not true, iterator can handle concurrent removals, as long as you don't modify the list during the process.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is faster because it does not involve shifting all of the subsequent elements when the element at the current position is removed.

When it comes to larger `ArrayList`s, I even dare to say that the first option is an anti-pattern.

Comment: You're assuming your `List` is always array based. If it were a linked list, then this won't be an issue.

Comment: True, but the question is about the `ArrayList`.

Comment: You are ignoring the overhead, that requires an arraylist to rebuild when the intial capacity is reached. This is alot more expensive (array-copy-complexity).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP explicitly asked about ArrayList

Comment: @SME_Dev True also, but to avoid that I usually give the new list the initial capacity that is equal to the size of the original list: `newList = new ArrayList<>(list.size())`